# Insert data into database using asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi i am trying to insert data in to database which is filled by user. I am using visual studio 2010 Asp.net mvc 2. But I am getting error

```
The resource cannot be found./Fillcustomer/customerdetail
```

.But the server name, user id and password is correct.  Please correct my code .

customer.cs

---

```
 namespace displaycustomer.Models
{
    public class customer
    {
        public int id { set; get; }
        public string customercode { set; get; }
        public int amount { set; get; }   

    public int Insert(int cid,string ccode, int amount)
    {

        string sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
        cn.Open();           
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblcus(C_Id, C_Code, Amount) " +
            " VALUES('" + cid + "','" + ccode + "', '" + amount + "')", cn);
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           

    }
}
```

}

### customerdetailcontroller.cs

```
    namespace displaycustomer.Controllers
{
    public class customerdetailController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /customerdetail/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Fillcustomer()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult insert()
        {
            customer cus = new customer();
            int id = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["customerid"]);
            string code = Request.Form["customercode"].ToString();
            int amt = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["amount"]);
            int _records = cus.Insert(id, code, amt);
            if (_records > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("customerdetail", "Fillcustomer");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Can Not Insert");
            }
            return View(cus);
        }

    }
}
```

### fillcustomer.aspx

```
<form method="post" action="insert">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Id</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="customerid" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Customer Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="customercode" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amount" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

### web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnString" connectionString="server=servername; Initial Catalog=sample; UID=user; pwd=123; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: error ? what you get as error

Comment: which means error in your connection to sql.. conn string might be wrong...

Comment: if you don't use sql parameter your code maybe got Sql Injection one day :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in connection string.
I had used this format. May be this can help you

```
<add name="ProductEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Sam.mdf;Password=12345;User Id=ABC;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

where the file Sam.mdf was in App_Data folder.

Ok now your url is incorrect.

It should be in the Format as /Controller Name/Method Name

It should be

```
 /customerdetail/FillCustomer
```

not

```
/Fillcustomer/customerdetail
```

change this

```
 public ActionResult insert()
    {
        customer cus = new customer();
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["customerid"]);
        string code = Request.Form["customercode"].ToString();
        int amt = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["amount"]);
        int _records = cus.Insert(id, code, amt);
        if (_records > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Fillcustomer", "customerdetail");//change this
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Can Not Insert");
        }
        return View(cus);
    }
```

RedirectToAction method takes 1st argument as action name and 2nd argument as controller name

Comment: i got the new error which i mention above pls help me to recover